# By which convention 04 (for example) is no valid 2 digit number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

When a person asks: "What is the smallest number (natural numbers) with two digits?"

You answer: "10".

But by which convention 04 is no valid 2 digit number?

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer would be $0$ has no value infront of a number.So,$04,004,0004,000000000004$ are all same.As,this $0$ has no meaning or significance in the representation of the number,$0$ infront of a number is not considered.

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for a *number*, not a *representation* of a number.

The digit sequence `04` is a representation of the number $4$ (also known as $1+1+1+1$), but `4` is *also* a representation of that same number.

Every natural number has many such representations, with varying amounts of leading zeroes, but when the question asks about a "number with two digits" it mus implicitly assume that a number *has* a well-defined number of digits. The only reasonable way to make sense of that is it interpret the question as

> What is the smallest number whose *usual decimal representation* has two digits?

(where "usual" means with no leading zeroes except that $0$ itself is represented as `0` because using the empty string of digits to represent something would be confusing).

$4$ does not qualify as an answer to this because its *usual* representation is `4` rather than `04`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context of the problem. For example. A number $n$ is called "magical" if $n^2$ ends with the digits of $n$. Below is a list of the first six magical numbers whose units digit is $5$.

```
 5²      =           25   
 25²     =          625    
 625²    =       390625    
 0625²   =       390625    
 90625²  =   8212890625    
 890625² = 793212890625
```

In this case, I'd want to say that $0625$ is a magical four-digit number because $0625^2$ end with the digits $0625$.

If I told someone I was making a six-digit yearly salary, it would probably be wrong to say that $\$005489$ was a six-digit income.